# Kanji to Hiragana with KAKASI

Tags: java, ruby, translation

I'm using KAKASI library and recently bumped into the following issue: 
When I want to translate time from kanji to hiragana, I get the wrong translation. The problem is KAKASI doesn't translate the whole word, and instead translates kanji one by one(at least in some cases).

For example this:
十一時

is translated to this:じゅういちとき

Which is not correct. It should be like:
じゅういちじ

I know could start KAKASI with 
`Kakasi.kakasi('-JH -p', @time)`, get all the readings, and display manually the one I want. But it seems to be a bad decision.
Please tell me if there is another way to get the correct kanji->hiragana translation with KAKASI automatically.

Comment: Just being curious: Does it resolve 時間 correctly? As to your question: I have never used KAKASI, but if it doesn't do context lookup on numbers, I fear you have no choice to do it manually. How about words where the hiragana changes with the number, as in 一匹　vs. 二匹?

Comment: And one more: How do you want to deal with 一日? Depending on the (even wider) context, you would have to choose between いちにち or ついたち.

Comment: 時間 is resolved as じかん.  一匹 as いっぴき. 二匹 as にひき.  Good for me KAKASI resolves days in the month more or less correctly -  ついたち.  I decided to use MeCab, and it works fine mostly. But it doesn't recognize 一日 like  ついたち. It seems that  you are right, and the only way to get the correct result is to do everything manually...